# Read input whereas first line is no of test case

Tags: java

Write a program that prints the numbers from x to y. But for multiples of three print "Fizz" instead of the number and for the multiples of five print "Buzz". For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print "FizzBuzz".

Input format; First line is Number of test case T. Next line will have T integer denoted by N

Constraint 
1<=T<=10

Input 
2
3 15

```
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String user_input = scan.nextLine();
        String[] stringsArray = user_input.split(" ");

        int[] intArray = new int[stringsArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < stringsArray.length; i++) {
            intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringsArray[i]);
            System.out.println(intArray[i]);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: *Input format; First line is Number of test case T. Next line will have T integer denoted by N* **What**? `T` is a test case number. Ok. Where are `x` and `y`? What is a T integer denoted by N? What is N?

Comment: This looks like the normal fizz buzz problem. See this very familiar post OP: [FizBuzz program: how to make the output correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220916/fizbuzz-program-how-to-make-the-output-correct?rq=2)

Comment: The input format suggests there will be two lines, however you only read one.

Comment: and... WHAT is the question?? This site is for questions; not for assignments